# hide as low as from catalog magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, css, jquery

I want to ask, how to hide as low as for product that I give a tier price
I just want to hide it in a category, not on the product page.

anyone knows how to do it? I searched for it but I didn't find the solution for it.

Magento 1.9

Comment: And it will be without any price on category page?

Comment: now it show 2 price the original price and as low as price . in category I only want the original price

Comment: do you use any custom theme?

Comment: yes I use theme from themeforest